# Wordpress hardcoded homepage (not visible in admin panel)

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I am working with a custom themed WP installation.  The homepage appears to be customized in such a way that, even though Settings > Reading is set to "Your latest post", it actually displays something else (not a post) as the homepage.

After installing and using an e-commerce plugin, upon adding categories for the products, the homepage has actually become "Your latest post".  Where can I find the code that might override that setting (in the code, or in the database; not in the Settings) and actually point it to an php page?

Comment: Can you add the theme you are using and the name of the ecommerce plugin that you mention?

Comment: Check either home.php or front-page.php (Or perhaps something else depending on the theme)

Comment: @s_ha_dum The template is custom and cannot be shared.  The thing that "fixed" the issue was deleting the default sample post added by WP upon installation.  Newly added posts don't affect [WP e-Commerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/). Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own page template
create a post, select the custom type post dont fill in the content cause you already hardcoded it.

then set it as a homepage trough settings read and choose the static page

more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages (check out Creating your own page templates)